# Local datacenter is not defined : cassandraDB and expressJS

Tags: express, cassandra

I followed the instructions for connecting cassandraDB and expressJs (V4.16.1) here -> https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#cassandra

**but I am having this error in the browser**:

```
msg 
name    "ArgumentError"
info    "Represents an error that is raised when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid."
message "'localDataCenter' is not defined in Client options and also was not specified in constructor. At least one is required. Available DCs are: [datacenter1]"
```

**code index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints:['localhost'] });
client.connect(function(err, result){
console.log('cassandra connection done');
});
var getAlllogs = 'SELECT * FROM  logs.ourlogs';
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  client.execute(getAlllogs,[], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      res.status(404).send({msg:err});
    } else{
      res.render('index', {
        ourlogs: result.rows[0]
      })
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**code index.jade**

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 all logs
  ul
    each ourlog, i in ourlogs
      li #{ourlog.curTime}
```

**cassandra info**

```
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

**what did I miss?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the answer :**

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], localDataCenter: 'datacenter1', keyspace: 'yourkeyspacename' });
```

**ExpressJS team should edit it on their website**